# How to make a field validation dependent on another field usind array form setup in ZF2?

Tags: forms, validation, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-form-element

In my form I have a field `foo`, that should be unique in the database table. So I added a `Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists` to its validators list:

```
namespace Bar\Form\Fieldset;

use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface;

class BuzFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    protected $dbAdapter;

    public function __construct($name = null, $options = []) {...}

    public function setDbAdapter(AdapterInterface $dbAdapter) {...}

    public function init()
    {
        $this->add([
            'name' => 'id',
            'type' => 'hidden'
        ]);
        $this->add(
            [
                'name' => 'foo',
                'type' => 'text',
                'options' => [...],
                'attributes' => [
                    'required' => 'required',
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ]
            ]);
        ...
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return [
            'foo' => [
                'required' => true,
                'validators' => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'Regex',
                        'options' => [
                            'pattern' => '/.../',
                            'message' => _(...)
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        'name' => 'Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists',
                        'options' => [
                            'table' => 'buz',
                            'field' => 'foo',
                            'adapter' => $this->dbAdapter
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            ...
        ];
    }
}
```

Now I want to use the same form for updating entries and of course cannot get the form validated. So I need to make the `NoRecordExists` validation for this field dependent on the field `id`. If `id` is set (that means, it's updating, not a creating), all validators (e.g. here `Regex`) should be applied, but this one not. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at the [Callback](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.validator.callback.html) validator. This validator will give you access to the form context allowing you to get the values of other fields. Use the `NoRecordExists` validator inside the `Callback` validator to make it dependend. Something like this. I didn't test this, but you'll get the idea.

```
'foo' => [
    'required' => true,
    'validators' => [
        [
            'name' => 'Callback',
            'options' => [
                'callback' => function($value, $context = []) {
                    if (empty($context['id'])) {
                        return $this->noRecordExistsValidator->isValid($value);
                    }

                    return true;
                },
            ],
        ]
    ]
]
```

You'll need to inject the `NoRecordExistsValidator` as a dependency to this form class, or better yet create a seperate `InputFilter` and corresponding factories which fully setup the `InputFilter` and inject that instance into the `Fieldset` object.